# Como fazer sobrecarga de método em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Pessoal como conseguir emular sobrecarga de métodos em `javascript`?
Sei que alguns programadores conseguem, por exemplo, vou utilizar o gulp.

o gulp possui o método `.task`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('example-task', function(){
    console.log('running example-task')
})

gulp.task('example-task-2', ['example-task'], function(){
    console.log('running example-task')
})
```

mas se eu quiser rodar algumas `tasks` antes de outras, eu faco isso:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('example-task', function(){
    console.log('running example-task')
})

gulp.task('example-task-2', ['example-task'], function(){
    console.log('running example-task')
})
```

quando eu quiser rodar a `example-task-2`, eu rodo antes a `example-task`, 
porque a `example-task-2` é uma especie de `task` dependente de `example-task`.

Enfim, mas isso foi utilizado apenas pra exemplificar o que eu quero entender.
Percebam a assinatura do método `.task`

O primeiro parametro é uma `string`, e o segundo pode ser um array ou uma função anônima.
Como eu consigo isso? Como eu venho do JAVA, isso seria facil: escreveria dois métodos 
com o mesmo nome e mudaria apenas o parametro recebido, seria algo dessa forma:

```
public interface Gulp {
    public void task(String taskName, AnonymousFunction run);
    public void task(String taskName, List<Task> depencencies, AnonymousFunction run);
}
```

e no js, como seria?

Answer (score 3):

É commum em APIs flexiveis as funções aceitarem numero e tipo diferentes de parâmetros. Para separar as àguas e saber quem é quem em runtime pode inspecionar-se o `arguments` que é uma palavra reservada. No fundo uma variável tipo array disponivel dentro do escopo de qualquer função.

Poderia ser also assim:

```
function foo(){
    var fn, str, arr;
    if (typeof arguments[2] != 'undefined'){
        fn = arguments[2];
        arr = arguments[1]
    } else {
        fn = arguments[1];
    }
    // aqui podes fazer algo com fn, str e arr. Sendo que caso "!arr == true" então ela não foi passada à função
}
```

Neste exemplo verifico se foram passados 3 argumentos á função. Também daria para fazer de outra maneira iterando o `arguments`, mas ficas com uma ideia julgo.

Comment: caramba, o negocio é nada trivial então.. pq alem de numero diferente de parametros, as vezes precisamos filtrar via tipos.

Comment: @user155542 pois. É questão de não criar demasiadas possibilidades para não ficar complexo de gerir o código.

Answer (score 1):

No `javascript` você consegue chamar as funções mesmo não passando todos métodos, exemplo:

```
function foo(param1, param2) {
    console.log(param1);
    console.log(param2);
}
```

Se você chamar

```
foo(); // mostra undefined e undefined 
foo(1); // mostra 1 e undefined
foo(1, 2); // mostra 1 e 2
```

Porém, você consegue fazer algo similar ao `Object...`

```
function foo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
 }
```